# Remove single quotes in windows CMD output

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to achieve to get the output without single quotes.
Please help me if you have any ideas.

Example: The  below command I am using to read the test file having strings with enclosed single quotes `''`.

I want to display or get  the output without single quotes.

`for /F "tokens=1" %i in (test.txt) do  @echo %i`

Current output:

```
'testonesite'
'testtwosite'
'testhreesite'
'testfoursite'
```

Expected output like below.

```
testonesite
testtwosite
testhreesite
testfoursite
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace text in a variable by using this syntax: `%value:search=replace%`.

In your particular case you would also need to use `EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!` because the variable is processed in a for-loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1" %%i in (test.txt) do (
    set value=%%i
    echo !value:'=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set this character as your delimiter `'`:

```bat
for /f tokens^=1delims^=' %i in (test.txt)do @echo=%i

... or... 

for /f "tokens=1 delims='" %i in (test.txt)do @echo=%i
```